# Is Ramsay Bolton named after Gordon Ramsay?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Is Ramsay Bolton named after Chef Ramsay?

Both "Ramsays" are spelled the same way, and the syllable structure of "Bolton" is similar to "Gordon." Both can be sadistic bastards, albeit one is somewhat worse. And I'm going to guess that GRR Martin likely knows a culinary show or two, and is probably well aware of Ramsay the chef.

Comment: Origin of GRRM names: [Baby books, (English) history, foreign baby books, online generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTBQZBMQtOw).

Comment: I must have missed the hell's kitchen episode where Gordon feeds a baby to dogs.

Comment: Gordon Ramsay is purely portrayed to be as bad as he is. A lot of his “evil” is due to carefully cut scenes. If you watch the master chef aired in Britain and the one aired in the us, you see the difference between the two.

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm sure that's true. I'm guessing that, if GRRM named the former after the latter, it likely had a lot more to do with humor than his strong feelings regarding the atrocities committed by Chef Ramsay in the kitchen.

Comment: @NeoDarwin the dogs criticized the baby for not being cooked enough and too salty, so the producers decided not to air it.

Comment: The real question is, is Gordon Ramsey named after Flash Gordon?

Comment: I mean, they both have a way with a knife don't they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Almost certainly not

The connection you mention is extremely tenuous at best. Apart from the common name “Ramsay” where one is the first name and the other is the surname the character/person are nothing alike. You mention Gordon Ramsay is a “sadistic bastard” but he isn’t really is he? He gets irate at incompetent chefs in a high pressure situation, I’d call that a short temper.

With that said George has been asked in the past if he based Ramsay on anyone and the response was a resounding no. I’m sure if he’d named him after the chef he would have spoken up about it given the opportunity.

> Was Ramsay inspired by any real people George knows? Laughter from the crowd, and then, "No, not really," from George. More laughter.
>
> <sub>[Westeros, So Spake Martin, STOCKHOLM AND ARCHIPELACON REPORT](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Stockholm_and_Archipelacon_Report)</sub>

Comment: Just to add to this, Gordon Ramsay didn't really gain widespread renown for being the short tempered chef until the mid 00's (after Kitchen Nightmares in the UK and then Hell's Kitchen in the US, in 2004/2005 respectively), which was more than half a decade after Ramsay first appeared in the books, so either GRRM knew something most didn't, or it was pure coincidence.